# What keyboard layout has a cedilla Ç next to the Enter key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have purchased a Microsoft Surface 3 from Ebay which seems to have had its Windows version changed. I have the usual " vs @ keys are swapped problems but none of the usual US/UK/International keyboard types solve it. I also notice it has a cedilla C next to what appears to be an International keyboard Enter key style.

So I'm wondering what keyboard this is? Canadian French? Spanish? Can someone tell me what keyboard layout I should select for this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Spanish standard keyboard layout (not International).

This is the layout from
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Spanish):

[image]

Comment: As a Spanish speaker, I have no idea what that character could be used for. Looking at the linked article, apparently it's "required only for typing Catalan and Occitan". TIL.

Comment: You can add the portuguese keyboard PT_pt . The ç is in a different position as the ~ is a standalone modifier.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be a Spanish (international) keyboard layout :)

[Link showing spanish keyboard layout](https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/how-to-type-the-at-sign-on-a-spanish-keyboard)

Answer (score -1):

Is a Portuguese layout from Portugal

Comment: Are you sure? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#Portugal) the Portuguese keyboard doesn't look like that.